# Search Tagtable with multiple tags or 'Select all exept' in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, tags

Is there a way to select all except those who match?

I am working with a tag table (article_id, tag) and an article table (article_id, title, ...);

My current problem: The existing search worked like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `article_id` FROM `TagTable` WHERE `tag` IN ('tag1', 'tag2')
```

Unfortunately this way the user gets the results that contain either one of the tags while you would only want articles that match both tags.

How would you implement it? Several subqueries for each tag seems a dumb idea. My idea would be to select all and remove everyone that dose not have each of the tags. 
Any better Ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try saying WHERE NOT IN ... ??

Comment: That would still require a subquery I guess. Maybe thats avoidable?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm pretty sure you can just say WHERE tag NOT IN ('tag1', 'tag2').

Comment: I mean to get those I want. I actually want all those with the tags, the get all except was just my approach. And if I'm not passing all the other tags I'll need a subquery to get all and then exclude those NOT IN the tags I want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hmm.

Well the easiest way is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM articles a
WHERE a.id IN (
    SELECT article_id FROM TagTable WHERE tag = 'tag1'
) AND a.id IN (
    SELECT article_id FROM TagTable WHERE tag = 'tag2'
);
```

But since you said you don't want to do that, you could try something like:

```
SELECT article_id, count(DISTINCT tag)
FROM TagTable
WHERE tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2')
GROUP BY article_id
HAVING count(DISTINCT tag) = 2
```

I haven't tested it yet, but something like that should work. you just have to make sure the HAVING clause equals the number of tags you are looking for.

Comment: I guess I'll have to get used to using subquerries if they are so commonly used. Anyway your second idea works perfectly. Thank you for that. Very creative.

Comment: With all things SQL, you should use whichever query is faster. I honestly can't say which of these two would be faster in this situation but I suspect the 2nd would be since it's explain plan is simpler.